# How to extrapolate using cuRe package in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, extrapolation

I am fitting a non-mixture cure model in R with splines, using the cuRe package. Here is my example:

```
dat <- cuRe::colonDC

non_mcm_spl_3df <- GenFlexCureModel(formula = Surv(FUyear, status) ~ 1,
                                    smooth.formula =  ~ ns(log(FUyear), df = 3),
                                    data = dat,
                                    type = "nmixture")

plot(non_mcm_spl_3df)
```

I wish to do this for multiple models and plot them all in a single plot using ggplot2. This is easy to do using flexsurv functions in R as you can use `summary` to extract coefficients specifying time points for extrapolation. I think it could be possible using predict here, but the output does not give me time points and I wish to extrapolate the model to 50-years on the graph, which I am not sure how to do. Any advice appreciated.

```
non_mcm_spl_3df_line <- as.data.frame(predict(non_mcm_spl_3df, type = "surv"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible via the `predict` function. Predictions at certain time points can be specified by using the `time` argument:

```
predict(fit.gen.timevar, time = c(2, 5, 50)).
```

The `predict` function can provide numerous functionals. This is specified via the `type` argument and the default is "surv", which is total survival. If you want to plot this functions, there is a `time` argument to the `plot` function:

```
plot(non_mcm_spl_3df, time = seq(0.001, 50, length.out = 100))
```

The `plot` function calls the `predict` function and thus the `type` argument can be used here in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks Lasse - is it possible to then plot this ? If you use my example above, you will see a plot to 20 - how to do this up until 50?